# Why did not delete table records in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Working with Laravel and has table called as **vehicles** and I need delete table records who are logged with the app and related to create records with logged user.  I am showing logged user records with following:

Vehicle model:

```
public function scopePersonal($query)
{
     return $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
}
```

VehcicleController:

```
public function indexpersonel()
{
    $vehicles = Vehicle::personal()->get();
    return view('vehicles.myads')->withVehicles($vehicles);
}
```

My ads delete buttons link:

```
<td><a class="button is-outlined" href="/myads/{{$vehicule->id}}/delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to want to delete this record?')" >Delete</a></td>
```

Vehicle controller delete function:

```
public function deleteOneAd($id)
{
    DB::table('vehicles')
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->delete();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

But when I clicked delete button and accept javascripts popup it is not deleting vehicles table records. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: No, any replay here?

Comment: Is `{{$vehicule->id}}` a typo here or is that your real code? I am guessing it should be `$vehicle`.

Comment: What is `withVehicles()`?  We also can't see your JS code which actually calls your `deleteOneAd()` method.

Comment: Are you sure there is a vehicle with that id in the database? Your `where` query could simply be returning zero results.